# Creating recursive mergesort method

Tags: java, mergesort

I am currently trying to implement the merge sort method to sort an array filled with random numbers. The main method tells whether the array is properly sorted or not.

So far, I have written the method to the best of my ability but no matter what I try I cannot understand why my merge sort is not working. I dont understand merge sort very well, so any help is appreciated

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] start = new int[100];
        for(int i = 0; i < start.length; i++)
        {
            start[i] = (int)(Math.random()*20 + 1);
        }
        int[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(start,start.length);
        Arrays.sort(sorted);
        mergesort(start);
        if(Arrays.equals(start, sorted))
            System.out.print("correctly sorted");
        else
            System.out.print("not properly sorted");
    }
    
    
    public static void mergesort(int[] arr)
    {
        //base case then general case
        //all merging code, no sorting

        //base case
        if(arr.length ==0 || arr.length < 2 || arr.length <=1)
        {
            return;
        }
        //divide
            int half = arr.length/2;
            int[]arr1 = new int[half];
            for(int i =0; i<half; i++)
            {
                arr1[i] = arr[i];
            }
            int[]arr2 = new int[arr.length - half];
            for(int i =half; i<arr.length; i++)
            {
                arr2[i-half]= arr[i];
            }

            //merging
            int[]merge = new int[arr1.length+arr2.length];

            int k = 0;
            int i=0;
            int j=0;
            while(i<arr1.length && j<arr2.length)
                {
                    if(i<arr1.length && (j>=arr2.length || arr1[i]<=arr2[j]))
                    {
                        merge[k++] = arr1[i++];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        merge[k++] = arr2[j++];
                    }
                }
            
                while(i<arr1.length)
                {
                    merge[k++] = arr1[i++];
                }

                while(j<arr2.length)
                {
                    merge[k++] = arr2[j++];
                }


        
        
    }

}
```

Everytime I run the code, I always get "not properly sorted"

Comment: if you don't understand merge sort, the first step should not be to try and code stuff, but to read up on how merge sort works. https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/data-structure-tutorial/merge-sort-algorithm#:~:text=Merge%20sort%20is%20one%20of,sublists%20into%20a%20sorted%20list. also: in the code you posted, the entire mergesort method is in comment, so the code as posted won't even compile, let alone run

Comment: And can you not see for yourself that `if(arr.length ==0 || arr.length < 2 || arr.length <=1)` is exactly equivalent to `if(arr.length < 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

After splitting `arr` into `arr1` and `arr2`, mergesort needs to call itself to sort `arr1` and `arr2`, then merge `arr1` and `arr2` back into `arr`. Fixes noted in comments. Also cleaned up some of the code and spacing.

```
public static void mergesort(int[] arr)
{
    //base case then general case
    //all merging code, no sorting

    //base case
    if(arr.length < 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    //divide
    int half = arr.length/2;
    int[]arr1 = new int[half];
    for(int i=0; i<half; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = arr[i];
    }
    int[]arr2 = new int[arr.length - half];
    for(int i=half; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr2[i-half]= arr[i];
    }

    mergesort(arr1);                // fix
    mergesort(arr2);                // fix

    // arr = merge(arr1, arr2)      // fix

    int k = 0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(i<arr1.length && j<arr2.length)
    {
        if(arr1[i]<=arr2[j])
        {
            arr[k++] = arr1[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
        }
    }

    while(i<arr1.length)
    {
        arr[k++] = arr1[i++];
    }

    while(j<arr2.length)
    {
        arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }
}
```